# How to mix eshell and elisp code

Tags: eshell, shell-command

If I'm in eshell I can run elisp commands cause I'm in an elisp runtime

```
(mapcar (lambda (x) (* x 3)) (list 1 2 3))
(3 6 9)
```

I can also run "shell" commands such as `git status`. But what if I wanted to take the output of my `git status` and pass it into a `mapcar`. How would I do that?

Comment: How about?:  `(let ((result (shell-command-to-string "git status"))) (stringp result))`  That example will return `t` at the eshell command prompt.  In terms of plugging that into your example, more details would be needed to know whether the result needs to be converted to a list for the SEQUENCE argument of `mapcar` or whether it would be plugged into the FUNCTION argument of `mapcar`.

Comment: `shell-command-to-string` seems to be what I needed (I'm just going to split by newline) Thanks! If you move it to an answer I'll mark it as answered.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For something simple, `shell-command-to-string` may suffice.  For something more complicated where the output needs to be modified, searched, etc., then something more elaborate may needed e.g., `set-process-sentinel`; `start-process`; `set-process-filter`, etc. and then take the result and plug it in.  The following example will return `t` because the output of `git status` has been converted to a string using `shell-command-to-string` and the output in the example is tested with `stringp`.

```lisp
(let ((result (shell-command-to-string "git status")))
  (stringp result))
```